# Microsoft Word: table padding margin not working

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

So I have this handsome table in my Word 2010 document:

[image]

All I want to do is to add a column to it. However, I get:

[image]

The cells have a margin/padding/whatever! The margins are set to 0. Things like autofitting, adding a column somewhere else etc do not help. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I was not able to duplicate this issue. What happens if you use format painter from a surrounding column?

Comment: When I add some column, it do the same in my document, but now when I mark the row and click on appropriate cell alignment, it fix the newly added cell. When I do it for all rows, problem is solved.

Comment: As a quick fix have you tried copying and pasting a column instead of inserting a new one?

Comment: @Dolmayan: What do you mean with 'appropriate cell alginment'?

Comment: When you add some column, you have status as on your second picture. Select an entire row, right click on mouse and choose Cell Alignment > {select_alignment_you_want}. It should fix margins of newly added cell in column.